# Creating an NSDictionary by writing values inside curly braces

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-literals

The `NSDictionary` class allows me to initialise it like this:

```
NSDictionary* attributes =
@{
  NSFontAttributeName: font
};
```

What is this construction method called, and how I can implement it in my own class? I want to have a class with properties that have default values, and I'd like to only set the ones I need during construction (in C++ I would have done this with default parameter values, but Objective-C does not have that), so this seemed like a legitimate approach. Or is this something `NSDictionary` specific?

Comment: Can't you set the default values of your properties in the class `init`? Or maybe create multiple `init`'s for the different cases?

Comment: Of course I can, simply I would like to avoid writing any init methods at all (somewhat similar like the C# property initializer ctor syntax), but if this extension is not for that then well - no luck.